# SQL procedure - changing value of table column based on count on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `property` and `component`. `component.id_property = property.id`.

I'm trying to create a procedure, which counts components on selected property and if there are no components for selected property, it change `property.id_state` to 1.

```
create PROCEDURE property_statement_change AS
BEGIN
declare @value int;

select 
    @value = count(c.value)
from
    component c
where
    c.id_property = 1
group by c.id_property

IF (@value = 0)
  UPDATE property
  SET id_state = 1
  WHERE property.id = 1
END
```

If I execute stored produre, it doesn't change anything, but select and also update works right. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you have looks correct.  It will only update the property (id_state to 1) if the count is 0.  Before your IF, try SELECT @Value and see if it is 0

Comment: Are you certain the @value = 0?

Comment: Aha, I'm idiot, `@value is null` :-)

Comment: Create the answer if you want and I'll accept it :-) Thank you both

Comment: @gaffcz least you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like stated on the comments, value is NULL instead and not 0, so here's the code:

```
create PROCEDURE property_statement_change AS
BEGIN
declare @value int;

select 
    @value = count(c.value)
from
    component c
where
    c.id_property = 1
group by c.id_property

IF (@value is NULL)
  UPDATE property
  SET id_state = 1
  WHERE property.id = 1
END
```